# bundle exec rake fails when pulling user attribute into mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't get `bundle exec rake` or `rspec spec` to pass even though all individual tests pass and the mailer that the error references works correctly (e.g. it successfully sends the email with all attributes). This is causing my Travis build to fail. The error is:

```
/app/views/team_mailer/new_team.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_team_mailer_new_team_html_erb__3000815885147353905_70129791802460': undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

/app/models/team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :picks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true

  after_create :send_new_team_email

  private
  def send_new_team_email
    TeamMailer.new_team(self).deliver_now
  end
end
```

/app/controllers/teams_controller.rb

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_user_for_delete, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :authorize_user_for_edit, only: [:edit]

  def index
    @user_teams = Team.where(user_id: current_user)
  end

  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def create
    @team = current_user.teams.build(team_params)

    if @team.save
      flash[:notice] = "Team successfully created."
      redirect_to @team
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating team. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name)
  end
```

/app/mailers/team_mailer.rb

```
class TeamMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "Support@coolsite.com"

  def new_team(team)
    headers["Message-ID"] = "<#{team.user_id} team/#{team.id}@Pcoolsite.com>"
    headers["In-Reply-To"] = "<#{team.user_id} team/#{team.id}@coolsite.com>"
    headers["References"] = "<#{team.user_id} team/#{team.id}@coolsite.com>"

    @team = team

    mail(to: 'me@gmail.com', subject: "New team created")
  end
end
```

/app/views/team_mailer/new_team.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content = "text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= "#{@team.user.first_name} #{@team.user.last_name} created #{@team.name}" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have 'current_user' in test env? Check your db, maybe team.user is not set.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by 'having a current_user' in test env? In my development database there are users and teams and they are properly associated. I was thinking this is failing because of bad tests but if I remove the team tests, `rspec spec` and `bundle exec rake` still fail.

Comment: If you build a team like `user.teams.build(name: 'test')`: is the team properly associated with the user?

Do I get you right: when you are running all tests, then you get the error. When you run that test in isolation, then you no error?

Comment: When I run individual tests, everything passes. When I use `rspec spec` and not identify any specific test, I receive the `.first_name` undefined method error. When I run binding.pry on my controller and view, the variable is passed okay. ```[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f86bfb4c0d8>>)> @team.user
=> #<User id: 4, email: "test@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-10-18 22:09:15", updated_at: "2017-08-19 17:15:47", role: "member", first_name: "Test", last_name: "User", verified: false>```

Comment: The full error is `undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by validating class is not nil in /app/views/team_mailer/new_team.html.erb.

I also realized it was overkill to pass user. So, I eliminated the passing of  it between models, controllers and views and just used `@team.user.first_name and @team.user.last_name`.

So the full line in /new_team.html.erb now reads:

`<%= "#{@team.user.first_name} #{@team.user.last_name} created #{@team.name}" if @team.user %>`

I updated the original posting to show the streamlined (removed user) approach.